# Работа с функцией def и смысл return

Tags: python, список

Результат работы моей функции - получение списка из  данных получаемых извне. Я эту функцию повторяю много раз с определенной периодичностью.

```
def my_func():
    my_list = []
    my_list.append (1,2,3,4)
    my_list = [1,2,3,4]
    print (my_list[0])  # 1
    print (my_list) # [1,2,3,4]
    my_list.clear()


for _ in range (3):
    my_func()
```

Эта функция работает в цикле с периодичностью и выводит мне списки, которые могут меняться. CLEAR нужен для очистки списка в конце, чтобы в начале он был пуст - обновился. Но мне не нужен print здесь, я хочу получить данные (списки) для дальнейшей работы. Пробую заменить print на return.

```
 def my_func():
        my_list = []
        my_list.append (1,2,3,4)
        my_list = [1,2,3,4]
        print (my_list[0])  # 1
        return (my_list)
        my_list.clear()


    for _ in range (3):
        my_func()
```

И этот код не работает, срабатывает только один раз, на второй заход цикла выдает ошибку "list index out of range", в строке с выводом определенного индекса списка, потому что my_list не обновился, а продолжился заполняться элементами списка. Clear не сработал после return, а если его поставить на строку выше, то return ничего не выдаст.

Мне нужно, чтобы моя функция работала и выдавала актуальные списки.

Comment: Верните копию, а исходный список очистите

Answer (score 1):

А Вы сами проверяли код который представлен в примере? У Вас переменная `my_list` создается 2 раза, первый раз вот так `my_list = []`, второй раз `my_list = [1,2,3,4]`. Функция `append` принимает одно значение, у Вас тут передается несколько. После вызова директивы `return` осуществляется "выход" из функцией с "удалением" локальных переменных, по этому `my_list.clear()` нет смысла использовать, да он и не вызывается он в вашем примере. Вот исправленный пример:

```
def my_func():
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(my_list[0])  # 1
    return my_list


for _ in range(4): 
    my_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы вероятно хотите начать с пустым списком, и потом после каждого вызова функции `my_func()` прибавить к ему следующие 4 элементы 1, 2, 3 и 4.

Прежде всего это не надо сдалат через функцию - когда вы хотите например список

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

вы можете просто писать

```
3 * [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Но когда вы однако хотите это сделать как функцию:

```
def my_func(my_list):
    my_list.extend([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Тестировка:

```
my_list = []

for _ in range (3):
    my_func(my_list)

print(my_list)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```